# Continuously Update Preview alert on SDL Tridion UI 2012

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to establish new SDL Tridion UI 2012 functionality on some test (default) pages. I am continuously retrieve "The preview for this page is not up to date" alert despite the fact that I click on "Update preview" several time. I was using virtual image, so anyone else is not possible to edit page except myself. No matters which component changed. I have taken a look into cd_core.log file on "session preview" web service side and find these nodes interesting:

```
INFO  WritableODataClaimProcessor - No session wrapper is installed, not allowing modification operations
DEBUG HandleSessionContentUtil - There are no session wrappers into storage config file!
DEBUG HandleSessionContentUtil - There are no session wrappers into storage config file!
DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStore@dc60af, thread: Thread-59
DEBUG WritableODataClaimProcessor - Removing sessionId claim from ClaimStore!
DEBUG ClaimStore - remove: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:preview:sessionid
DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: Thread-59
```

The most interesting part is that session wrappers were added to cd_storage_conf.xml on "session preview" web service side. Bellow is part of "session preview" cd_storage_conf.xml:

```xml
    <Storages>       
        <Wrappers>               
            <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">             
                <Timeout>120000</Timeout>                  
                <Storage Type="persistence" Id="sqlServerDb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                        <Property Name="serverName" Value="T2011" />
                        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Session_Preview"/>
                        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionSessionPreview"/>
                        <Property Name="password" Value="tridion"/>
                    </DataSource>
                </Storage>                   
            </Wrapper>
        </Wrappers>            
        <StorageBindings>
            <Bundle src="preview_dao_bundle.xml"/>            
        </StorageBindings>       
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="staging" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\software" />
        </Storage>
       <Storage Type="persistence" Id="sqlServerDb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="T2011" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Staging"/>
                <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser"/>
                <Property Name="password" Value="tridion"/>
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>
    </Storages>    
</Global>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlServerDb" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="staging"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

I have check cd_storage_conf.xml validity state and everything is OK (try to open XML via IE and it is showed correctly).

When I republish the page (Finish Editing) everything is correct state after reload the page until the first change on any components is made. This unexpected state gave me such a strong pain and headache, furthermore create me a so nervous... :).

Comment: @Frank Would you like to share with me  how to "colorize" code in order to became more readable ...

Comment: I added a <!-- language: c# --> tag before it. If you click on the timestamp of my edit (so the "14 minutes ago" text) you will see the exact diff. In addition I reindented your XML, which also helps readability a bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what Update Preview does, make sure all the steps up to the actual page refresh work and are correctly configured and you should be good to do:

1. Render your template(s) in Preview Mode
2. Post the results to the Content Delivery Web Service
3. CD Web Service writes to Session Wrapper Database
4. Refresh the page
5. Ambient Framework filters (or HTTP Modules for .NET) check for a session token
6. DB is queried searching for content with the same session token
7. If content is found, it is merged with the content on the page.

Typical issues (in my experience so far) are around Ambient Framework Configuration - Either the modules are not installed/configured on your application, or the cd_ambient_conf.xml contains invalid configuration settings.

Might be worth tracing the logs from step 1 to figure out where it's failing - knowing where it fails is usually 80% of the solution.

Comment: Both web.configs (web service and staging site contains reference to [Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule] inside [System.webserver\modules] and [system.web\httpModules]. Session preview web service contains [Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll] inside bin folder and [cd_preview_ambient.jar] and [cd_preview_webservice.jar] inside lib folders. Does exist any additional settings/configuration related to enabling ambient data framework? Cd_ambient_conf.xml contains only [<Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>] inside [Cartridges] node...

Comment: I have found following interesting inside session preview web service log [SessionManagerImpl - No claim store!!! Ambient framework is probably not enabled!]. On staging site inside cd_ambient_conf.xml exists [<ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>]. Also when edit some component fields I am able to see changes only if click on the field. I have checked and web service is installed as expect, it returns values...

Comment: The web service uses a different claim store (the default one) you should not change it. Have you tried using the pre-built web apps that ship with the installers? I would try comparing versions of DLLs and Jars (with something like Beyond Compare). You can find the pre-built apps under [UI install folder]\Content Delivery\roles\Web|WebService\dotNet

Comment: Issue resolved. [Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.dll] was placed on both session preview web service and staging site. Removing from session preview web service together with restarting IIS leads to complete UI functionality. @NunoThank you for showing me the way... . Anyway from my point of view it is excellent feature