# Tridion UI Error – “The preview for this page is not up to date ”

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have installed Tridion UI and getting below warning in the log file. Except this warning nothing is logged wrong in the log files even in debug mode.

> “WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context -
>   the ambient data framework is not properly initialised”

This warning get logged in my session preview web service  cd_core.2012-11-11.log  file  and in same log file of staging web application also.
 I am suspecting that due to this warning I am not getting updated preview of page in the UI interface. Please see below attached screenshot for the UI error –

[image]
 I also tried to update the preview by clicking on "update the page preview" button, but no luck.
To resolve this error I followed almost all answers related to this in the stack overflow. 
If I refer the answer in this below question.
[Tridion UI - Preview Not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351709/tridion-ui-preview-not-updating)
 So we are correct on this point as content get published in the right place always. I would like to explore the similar point from the setting in the cd_dynamic_conf.xml of Session Preview service is something like below –

```
<URLMappings>
    <StaticMappings>
<Publications>
 <Publication Id="241">
    <Host Domain="xyz" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/" />
</Publication>
  <Publication Id="121">
     <Host Domain="xyz" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/" />
</Publication>
</Publications>
   </StaticMappings>
<StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
</URLMappings>
```

And in the   of the staging application

```
     <URLMappings>
    <StaticMappings>
      <Publications>           
    <Publication Id="241">
     <Host Domain="xyz" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/" />
   </Publication>
    </Publications>
   </StaticMappings>
    <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
      </URLMappings>
```

And SiteEdit mark-up get created something like this –

For component presentation

```
 <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID":"cp_5", "ComponentID":"tcm:240-22393",             "ComponentVersion":19, "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:240-23899-32", "IsQueryBased":false} -->
```

For page setting

```
<!-- SiteEdit Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:240-22507-64", "PageVersion":49,     "TargetTypeID":"tcm:0-1-65438", "ComponentPresentationLocation":1} -->
```

Here I want to highlight few Important points as below -

1- I have web site in 2 languages one with /en and one with /fr under the same IIS directory.
In above  setting   publication id  241 is for my en version of website .so  I also tried  below setting

```
<Publication Id="240">
<Host Domain="xyz" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/en" />
</Publication>
```

But again no luck.
I can provide more information such as log files etc., if they are still required to investigate the issue.
Please help me to get rid of this very irritating issue on very earlier basis.

**Edit -1** Please also find below config files for same

**cd_ambient_conf.xml for Session Preview webservice**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">


    <!-- Cookies settings -->
    <!-- <Cookies> <Cookie Type="Tracking" Name="myTrackingCookie" Path="/"/> <Cookie Type="Session" Name="mySessionCookie" Path="/"/> </Cookies> -->
    <Cartridges>
        <!-- Example cartridge definition -->
        <!--
        <Cartridge File="cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
        -->
        <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
    </Cartridges>
</Configuration>
```

**cd_ambient_conf.xml for stagging website**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration Version="6.1"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">

        <Cartridges>

            <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
            <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>

        </Cartridges>
      <ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>

    </Configuration>
```

**cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xml for Staging website**

```
    <ClaimProcessorDefinitions>
        <ClaimProcessorDefinition Uri="tcd:claimprocessor:example:userdetails" ImplementationClass="com.tridion.ambientdata.processing.ExampleClaimProcessor1"
                            Description="Example claim processor that gets user details.">
            <RequestStart>
                <InputClaims>
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="tcd:claim:userid" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="tcd:claim:username" />
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="tcd:claim:usersex" />
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="tcd:claim:userage" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </RequestStart>
        </ClaimProcessorDefinition>

        <ClaimProcessorDefinition Uri="tcd:claimprocessor:example:example2"
                            ConfigProviderClass="com.tridion.ambientdata.processing.ExampleClaimProcessorConfigProvider" />
    </ClaimProcessorDefinitions>
</CartridgeDefinition>
```

**NOTE:- Reason why we have cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xml for staging website and not for 
 Session preview website**
during setting UI up , staging website was throwing an error in which it was expecting cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xml file.So we put a sample file in this website.Even it is no where mentioned in the documentation to have this file. but in case of session preview website ,it was not expecting any such file.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 6):

1. You can safely ignore the WARN message in the log. Preview is not up to date message is unrelated to this WARN message.
2. If you are using virtual paths for your web sites (like /en, /fr etc..) then you need to have the hotfix "CD_2011.1.1.81686" installed on preview application. You do not need to add virtual paths to cd_dynamic_conf.xml file. You should keep it just "/"
3. Lastly, related to "preview is not up to date", You need to add the cd_ambient_catridge_conf.xml to your web service also in addition to your preview too. I don't believe this is documented but AFAIR you need to add this, I don't have my VM readily accessible but I can confirm this later. Please make sure you comment out all the Example ClaimProcessors.

Also, make sure you have Session Preview enabled in CMS , Inline Editing settings (Disable Session Preview should be NO)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ram G for your reply. I was out of office from last few days. today I tried the solution provided by you . But still no luck. I am still facing same issue "preview is not up to date".

Comment: Typically most times this is something to do with your config (ambient conf). Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788508/continously-update-preview-alert-on-sdl-tridion-ui-2012 for troubleshooting tips mentioned in the answer. Any erros in the logs of session preview web service and preview webapp?